# Как установить Parallels Tools на Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, macos, parallelstream

Не могу установить Parallels Tools на Ubuntu Server 16.

В самом Parallels Desktop какое-то мутное описание про установку. Да и гугление ни к чему не привело.

В общем проделал следующие команды:

```
$ sudo su
$ apt-get install gcc make
$ mkdir -p /media/cdrom
$ mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
$ cd /media/cdrom
$ ./install
```

И в итоге ловлю ошибку:

> An error occurred when installing Parallels Tools

Comment: какая версия pt?

Comment: Если с документацией и инструментарием всё так фигово - может стоит подумать о смене виртуалки?